# How can I change icon class based the value of a field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I change a icon class based on a field value? I have a field name called `flag`, this field contains two value `On` and `Off`.

How can i change icon class based on the value:

> When flag="On" show this icon `fa-check-circle` green
>      When flag is off show `k-i-close-outline`

```
<ul id="treeview" >
     @foreach (var item in rpInfo)
         {
          <li data-expanded="true" class="panel-handler" data-id="@item.ID">
              <i class="far fa-check-circle" data-id="@item.Flag" style="padding-right: 10px;"></i>@item.CompanyName
                 <ul>
                    <li data-expanded="true">  
                     <i class="far fa-check-circle"></i>@item.flag @item.ContactName 
                   </li>
                 </ul>
               </li>
          }
    </ul>
```

To make it easier i added `data-id` as   and in browser looks like this `<i class="far fa-check-circle" data-id="Off" style="padding-right: 10px;"></i>`.

may be if that helps

Thank you!

Comment: That flag field is stored where? On server database? Simply do a select and check for on or off than echo different things for those two options.

Comment: @ikiK Sorry what do you mean by `That flag field is stored where? ` you mean in my code?

Comment: Now i also added in <i></> tag as `<i class="far fa-check-circle" data-id="@item.Flag" style="padding-right: 10px;"></i>`

Comment: it isn't plain javascript or jQuery, what else are you using here?

Answer (score 0):

I'm having trouble to understand what you do and what you need but it sounds like you need a simple [if statement](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_if.asp).

Maybe something along the lines?

```
    <ul id="treeview" >
         @foreach (var item in rpInfo)
             {
             var flag = @item.Flag;
            if (flag = 'On') { '
              <li data-expanded="true" class="panel-handler" data-id="@item.ID">
                  <i class="far fa-check-circle" data-id="@item.Flag" style="padding-right: 10px;"></i>@item.CompanyName
                     <ul>
                        <li data-expanded="true">  
                         <i class="far fa-check-circle"></i>@item.flag @item.ContactName 
                       </li>
                     </ul>
                   </li>
         '} else{ '
              <li data-expanded="true" class="panel-handler" data-id="@item.ID">
                  <i class="k-icon k-i-close-outline" data-id="@item.Flag" style="padding-right: 10px;"></i>@item.CompanyName
                     <ul>
                        <li data-expanded="true">  
                         <i class="k-icon k-i-close-outline"></i>@item.flag @item.ContactName 
                       </li>
                     </ul>
                   </li>
               '}
};
        </ul>
```

Comment: I like it but when i copied <li>..</li> section to here ` //something else..` as you mention on the else statement it gives me error +99 error i dont see any unclosed bracket or anything. to copy everything and change the icon

Comment: can i copy the whole thing in li tag to the else statement and change the icon?

Comment: Yes that would be the point. two similar codes run on two conditions. But I don't know if it will work cose I don't see your flag value, try adding alert(flag);  before if condition you  to see if you will get On or Off alert.

Comment: add `alert(flag); ` only or i have to add something else? alert(flag);  it giving me error

Comment: You need to found out what @item.Flag has value. Then when you see what that is you can make a condition based on that. Cant help you more then that, this is way to few information.

Comment: Try in your original code: alert(@item.Flag); just after your opening <li tag. And see what that gives you.

Comment: i literally mentioned that flag = on or off. depending on the record

Comment: So you got an popup JS alert saying: falg = on or of ? Cant be.

Comment: If is literally on or off my first code should work

Comment: Actually i think there was missing } at end.

Comment: here  see something, when its off nothing displayed. but i added `alert(@item.Flag);` nothing displayed. when its on everything displayed as my orginal code

Comment: No error because i dont have anything in the else statement. I want the same code what we have in the if statement but this `class="far fa-check-circle"` changed. when i do that i get a bunch of errors . if we fix that i think all will work.

Comment: I dont understand it ikik we cant use <li> tag in else? i get same thing im sorry

Comment: Do you maybe have a public link to this?

Comment: sorry for the late reply, no i don't have a public link